# Find duplicates in SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this table named log:

```
ID   User_ID   Machine_Number   Email 
1     100         12345          jim@gmail.com
2     100         12345          jim@gmail.com
3     101         67890          bill@gmail.com
4     102         12345          steve@gmail.com
```

I need to find the User_IDs of users with the same Machine_Number.  In this case, I need a query that returns 100 and 102.

I've tried:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(machine_number) 
FROM log
GROUP BY machine_number
HAVING COUNT(machine_number) > 1
```

but that gives the count of each occurrence of the machine_number, i.e.
User_ID   Count(machine_number)

```
100          2
101          1
102          1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code is in MS SQL syntax, but I think it will work fine in MYSQL.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t1.User_ID FROM log t1 
    INNER JOIN 
     (
    SELECT l.Machine_Number,count(DISTINCT l.User_ID)Count FROM log l
    GROUP BY l.Machine_Number
    )t2
    ON 
    t1.Machine_Number =t2.Machine_Number
    WHERE t2.Count>1
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to get both user_id against same machine. Try `group_concate`:

```
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT user_id), machine_number
FROM log
GROUP BY machine_number
HAVING COUNT(machine_number) > 1
```

Comment: This one gives user_ids of 
100,100,102
I need it to just give 100,102 and skip the duplicate

Comment: @SilenceKit you can simply add `distinct` in `group_concate`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean *different* uses with the same machine.  You can use `exists` like this to get the original rows:

```
select l.*
from log l
where exists (select 1
              from log l2 
              where l2.machine_number = l.machine_number and l2.email <> l.email
             );
```

This should have very good performance, particularly with an index on `(machine_number, email)`.

Answer (score 0):

use exists

```
select distinct t1.* from log t1 where exists
( select 1 from log t2 where t1.machine_number=t2.machine_number
 group by machine_number having count(*)>1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id,Machine_Number 
FROM log where Machine_Number IN 
     (SELECT Machine_Number FROM log GROUP BY Machine_Number HAVING count(1) > 1) 
ORDER BY Machine_Number;
```

And if you want distinct user_id then use below.

```
SELECT distinct user_id, Machine_Number
FROM log where Machine_Number IN
(SELECT Machine_Number FROM log GROUP BY Machine_Number HAVING count(1) > 1) 
ORDER BY Machine_Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DISTINCT M.User_Id, M.Machine_NUmber from Machine M  
Inner Join (Select M1.Machine_NUmber from Machine M1 Group By M1.Machine_NUmber Having COUNT(M1.Machine_NUmber)>1) M2 
On M.Machine_NUmber = M2.Machine_NUmber
```

Comment: A blob of code is not a great answer. Convince us that this addresses the question posed with a short explanation.